# How to pass parameter into React component defined using ES6 class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this simple Blog component defined in ES6 class way:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Blog extends React.Component {
  Sidebar(props) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {props.posts.map(post => (
          <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  posts = [
    { id: 1, title: "Hello World", content: "Welcome to learning React!" },
    { id: 2, title: "Installation", content: "You can install React from npm." }
  ];

  render() {
    return (
        <this.Sidebar posts={this.posts} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Blog />, document.getElementById("root"));

export default Blog;
```

When I want to pass variable `posts` to `Sidebar` props I can write

```
<this.Sidebar posts={this.posts} />
```

in render method.

However, if I export the Blog component and import it like this (variable `posts` is removed from the Blog component):

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Blog from './Blog'

const posts = [
    { id: 1, title: "Hello World", content: "Welcome to learning React!" },
    { id: 2, title: "Installation", content: "You can install React from npm." }
  ];

ReactDOM.render(<Blog posts={posts} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

It does not seem working. How can I pass variable `posts` to the imported `Blog` component?

Comment: Why just not use separate component for Sidebar?

Comment: You can use static component method, then you can render it as `<Blog.Sidebar>`.

Comment: If you're passing `posts` as `props` wouldn't it be `posts={this.props.posts}` instead of `posts={this.posts}`? Also, not really sure where you've seen this pattern before of doing `<this.Sidebar />` inside render but I'd suggest to stay away from doing this - move it to a separate component.

Comment: @dev_junwen Making a static component method for `Sidebar` still won't solve the problem that `this.posts` is no longer correct inside the `Blog` component.

Comment: @demkovych Do you mean define Sidebar as a component rather than defining Blog as a component and wrap Sidebar inside it?

Comment: Meaning you have 2 components, one for `Sidebar` and one for `Blog`, rather than having `Sidebar` as a property of the `Blog` component. Where did you pick this pattern from?

Comment: @goto1 I improvised a bit based on this example: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
In this example you can see Blog contains Sidebar and Content.

Comment: Yeah that's fine in `functional components` but if you want to replicate a similar approach with `class-based components` use the `compound components` pattern rather than what you're doing. Here's an example https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-swanson-rnmod?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark and here you can learn more - https://kentcdodds.com/blog/compound-components-with-react-hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you factor `posts` out as a global variable and pass it into the `Blog` component, it becomes `this.props.posts` inside of `Blog`:

```
class Blog extends React.Component {
  Sidebar(props) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {props.posts.map(post => (
          <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <this.Sidebar posts={this.props.posts} />           // <--- Change this
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define Sidebar as static method:-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Blog extends React.Component {

  // static sidebar component method
  static Sidebar(props) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {props.posts.map(post => (
          <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  posts = [
    { id: 1, title: "Hello World", content: "Welcome to learning React!" },
    { id: 2, title: "Installation", content: "You can install React from npm." }
  ];

  render() {
    return (
        <Blog.Sidebar posts={this.props.posts || this.posts} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Blog />, document.getElementById("root"));

export default Blog;
```

and pass props to it like this:-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Blog from './Blog'

const posts = [
    { id: 1, title: "Hello World", content: "Welcome to learning React!" },
    { id: 2, title: "Installation", content: "You can install React from npm." }
  ];

ReactDOM.render(<Blog.Sidebar posts={posts} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: `this.posts` won't work when you're passing them as `props`.

Comment: Thanks. Updated.

Comment: And that final change is the real solution. Static vs non-static doesn't make a difference here. The crucial change is from `this.posts` to `this.props.post`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice if the crucial change is from `this.posts` to `this.props.post` (and I have tested your answer and it works), is it needed to define Sidebar as static method? What's the benefit of each (i.e. use `this.props.post` vs define as static method)?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu "What's the benefit of each (i.e. use this.props.post vs define as static method)?" These are two different things and cannot be compared.